# AVfoundation, Firebase storage & Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, camera, firebase-storage, avfoundation

I'm trying to make a photo album using AVfoundation and saving it to firebase storage with a link to the photo in an album collection saved in firestore. But I'm running in to some issues with my camera. It seems like my *"photOutput"* function is not being called. This leads to an Fatal error in savePost function on line `let image = UIImage(data: self.picData)!` that says: **Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseStorage


class cameraModel: NSObject, ObservableObject,  AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    @Published var isTaken = false
    @Published var session = AVCaptureSession()
    @Published var alert = false
    @EnvironmentObject var album : AlbumViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var user : UserViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var post : PostViewModel
    
    
    
    // Since wew going to read pic data...
    @Published var output = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
    
    // preview
    @Published var preview : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    
    @Published var isSaved = false
    @Published var picData = Data(count: 0)
    
    
    func Check() {
        //first checking cameras got permission..
        switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for:  .video) {
        case .authorized:
            //setting up session
            setUp()
            return
        case .notDetermined:
            // retesting for permission...
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { (status) in
                if status {
                    self.setUp()
                }
            }
            
        case .denied:
            self.alert.toggle()
            return
        default:
            return
            
        }
        
    }
    
    func setUp() {
        // setting up camera
        
        do {
            
            // setting configs..
            self.session.beginConfiguration()
            
            // change for your own
            
            if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back) {
                
                do {
                    let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
                    
                    //checking and adding to session
                    
                    if self.session.canAddInput(input) {
                        self.session.addInput(input)
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                
                // Same for outputs...
                
                if self.session.canAddOutput(self.output) {
                    self.session.addOutput(self.output)
                }
                
                self.session.commitConfiguration()
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

        
        // take and retake functions...
        
        func takePic(){
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                self.output.capturePhoto(with: AVCapturePhotoSettings(), delegate: self)
                self.session.stopRunning()
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    withAnimation{self.isTaken.toggle()}
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
        func reTake() {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                self.session.startRunning()
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    withAnimation{self.isTaken.toggle()}
                    // clearing
                    self.isSaved = false
                }
            }
        }
        
        
        func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
            if error != nil{
                print("\(error!.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            print("pic taken...")
           // print("Image Data Size: \(imageData.count)")

            
            guard let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() else {return}
            self.picData = imageData
            
        }
        
   
    
    func savePost(albumUuid: String) {
        print(" \(picData.count)")
            let image = UIImage(data: self.picData)!
            let uuid = UUID().uuidString
            
            // Step 1: Upload the image to Firebase Storage
            let storage = Storage.storage()
            let storageRef = storage.reference()
            let imageRef = storageRef.child("\(uuid).jpg") // Unique name for the image
            let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8)
            let metadata = StorageMetadata()
            metadata.contentType = "\(uuid)/jpg"
            
            
            
            if let imageData = imageData {
                imageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: metadata) { metadata, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error uploading image: \(error)")
                    }
                    
                    if let metadata = metadata {
                        print("Metadata: \(metadata)")
                    }
                    
                    // Step 2: Once the image is uploaded, get the download URL
                    
                }
            }
        self.isSaved = true
        
        post.createPost(albumID: albumUuid, imageURL: uuid)
        }
    

    }

    
    
    //Setting view for preview...
    
    
    struct CameraPreview: UIViewRepresentable {
        
        @ObservedObject var camera : cameraModel
        func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
            
            let view = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            
            camera.preview = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: camera.session)
            camera.preview.frame = view.frame
            
            // Your own properties...
            
            camera.preview.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
            view.layer.addSublayer(camera.preview)
            
            //starting session
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                   camera.session.startRunning()
               }
            return view
        }
        
        func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
            
        }
    }
```

// Here is my cameraView:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct CameraView2: View {
    @StateObject var camera = cameraModel()
    @EnvironmentObject var album : AlbumViewModel
    @State var albumuuid : String
    @StateObject var fetchAlbums = FetchAlbums()
    @State private var selectedAlbumID: String? = nil
    
    
    var body: some View{
        ZStack{
            
            //Going to be the camera preview...
            CameraPreview(camera: camera)
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all)
            
            VStack{
                        
                        if camera.isTaken {
                            
                            HStack{
                                Spacer()
                                Button(action: camera.reTake, label: {
                                    Image(systemName: "arrow.triangle.2.circlepath.camera")
                                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                                        .padding()
                                        .background(Color.white)
                                        .clipShape(Circle())
                                })
                                .padding(.trailing,10)
                                
                            }
                        }
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        HStack {
                            
                            
                            // if taken showing save and again take button
                            
                            if camera.isTaken {
                                
                                
                                Button(action: {if !camera.isSaved{camera.savePost(albumUuid: albumuuid)}}, label: {
                                    Text(camera.isSaved ? "Saved" : "Save")
                                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                        .padding(.vertical,10)
                                        .padding(.horizontal,20)
                                        .background(Color.white)
                                        .clipShape(Capsule())
                                    
                                })
                                .padding(.leading)
                                Spacer()
                                
                            } else {
                                
                                Button(action: {camera.takePic()}, label: {
                                    
                                    ZStack{
                                        
                                        Circle()
                                            .fill(Color.white)
                                            .frame(width: 65, height: 65)
                                        
                                        Circle()
                                            .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
                                            .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                                    }
                                    
                                })
                            }
                        }
                        .frame(height: 75)
                        AlbumPickerView(fetchAlbums: fetchAlbums, selectedAlbumID: $selectedAlbumID)
                    }
            }
            .onAppear(perform: {
                camera.Check()
            })
        }
    }



struct AlbumPickerView: View {
    @ObservedObject var fetchAlbums: FetchAlbums
    @Binding var selectedAlbumID: String?

        var body: some View {
                Picker("Select an Album", selection: $selectedAlbumID) {
                    ForEach(fetchAlbums.queryResultAlbums, id: \.self.uuid) { album in
                        Text(album.albumName).tag(album.uuid)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(.menu) // Use .wheel for a wheel-style picker
                .onChange(of: selectedAlbumID) { newSelectedAlbumID in
                    // Handle the selection change if needed
                }
            }
        }
```

Any Ideas? 
I've been stuck with this for weeks now trying to find the solution. What could be worth saying is that in my CameraPreview struct I get two *Hang risk*. Saying:
 "*Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior.*"
 and "*-[AVCaptureSession startRunning] should be called from background thread. Calling it on the main thread can lead to UI unresponsiveness*". Not sure if it relates to the error.